# Search SharePoint Foundation 2013 Picture Library by terms defined in Keywords field

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-2013, search-engine, picturegallery

Since Term Store functionality (and probably most of metadata functionality) isn't available in SharePoint **Foundation** 2013, I couldn't find a way to search through the pictures using some sort of tagging. Thus I decided to employ something what is available already in Foundation version.

When you edit the picture, you can see 3 fields: **Title**, **Description** and **Keywords** like so: 
[image]

It would be nice if I could make Search index terms (tags) added to the Keywords field. However, after some testing I saw that only Title is indexed and presented in search results. Although I could use my search terms in Title field, it won't be elegant.

So, is there any way to make use of Keywords entity in my case? Please note, it's a Foundation version, so there is no Enterprise Keywords functionality either (or at least I couldn't find one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I used this kind of workaround in the end:

1. Went to my Picture Libraly's *Settings*
2. Chose to create a new column (this can also be done in Site *Settings > Site Columns*, if you want to reuse it for more sites)
3. Called the column **Primary Tags**
4. Chose *Single line of text option*, because multiple lines option [cannot be indexed](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__creating_sharepoint_indexed)
5. Because single line option is limited to 255 characters, I repeated steps 2-4 to create another column and named it **Secondary Tags**
6. Then went to *Indexed Columns* page and added those 2 new columns to the index

Now I have **Title**, **Primary Tags** and **Secondary Tags** indexed fields available for each picture with a total of 765 characters available.